# Power BI | Power Query: how to create multiple columns from one single value column

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, data-wrangling

I am currently using Power BI (Power Query) to clean up a dataset, and I am having some problems unpivotting a table the right way (see image below). Any suggestions on how to sort this out?

[image: link to image]

Comment: For reference, the Microsoft Docs page on [how to add an index column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/add-index-column) contains a step-by-step tutorial on how to pivot a table similar to yours. In your case, you already have the integer-divide column and only need to add a modulo column (based on an index column) as suggested by Marcus.

Comment: This is indeed useful - thanks, Patrick!

Answer (score 1):

For unpivoting to work you need three columns:

| Key | Column | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1.3 |
| 1 | B | 3 |
| 1 | C | New |
| 2 | A | 2.3 |
| 2 | B | 3 |
| 2 | C | Old |

So this could be unpivoted to:

| Key | Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.3 | 3 | New |
| 2 | 2.3 | 3 | Old |

So for this you would need to add a `column`-column where the row value is the column name - prior to unpivoting the table.

Edit:

If your rows are ordered according to columns per key, you can do something like this, where you create your own `column`-column prior to pivoting. See code you can paste into a blank query:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("Tcq7DQAgCAXAXV5tI0zAZwvC/muYaCSvu+KqsLFgZuj17O7jiBhn5rXQF/pCX+grfaWv9PX/Pg==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [id = _t, values = _t]),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Custom", each Number.Mod([Index],4)),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Index"}),
    #"Pivoted Column1" = Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns", {{"Custom", type text}}, "nb-NO"), List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns", {{"Custom", type text}}, "nb-NO")[Custom]), "Custom", "values")
in
    #"Pivoted Column1"
```

Comment: Thanks, Marcus! I might have used the word "unpivotting" inappropriately here as I don't have any extra column where the row value is the column name. Given the situation as described in the linked image, is there any feasible solution to the problem?

Comment: Well, you have to add a column that describes the column name. You can't do what you want by letting the computer "smell" what column is appropriate, you need to tell it what values go in which column - I assume you don't have `AAA` as actual values. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks, Marcus! I will give it a shot and mark this answer as useful.